# Might use help transcribing a sentence

Tags: pronunciation

Could someone please help me with the following:

What are man's words from 1:13 time mark to 1:16 in this video:
[How Were the Pyramids Built?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lotbZQ55SgU)

I'm making subtitles for that video, so I'd really like an accurate transcription. Both your guesses and positive replies are highly appreciated!

Thanks.
Anthony

Comment: Bearing in mind English is not this man's first language, sounds to me like: "Nobody know how they build it, it's [a] secret, but a lot of people they try to do their best to give you some information about how they did it. But we must say, it's secret. They did, and they take their secret [??] . Nobody know."

Comment: Not _they did_ but _the date_. "..secret. The date, and ????, nobody knows"

Answer (score 0):

Possibly,

> Nobody knows how they build it. It is still secret. But a lot of
>   people did try to do our best to give you some information about how
>   she did it; but we must say it is secret today as indeed a secret
>   then.